# trying to make graphics in VB suppose to make a J and make rotate but it keeps making a mess

Tags: arrays, vb.net, graphics

having trouble making it print a J and rotating it it crashes whenever i hit button 1 but works fine for the other things except making a correct J and i try changing the points and it still does that

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim g As Graphics
    Dim triangX(12) As Single
    Dim triangY(12) As Single

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PictureBox1.Width = 200
        PictureBox1.Height = 200
        PictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White
        g = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
        Call initTriangCoords(triangX, triangY)
        Timer1.Interval = 200
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub initTriangCoords(ByRef x() As Single, ByRef y() As Single)
        x(0) = 80 : y(0) = 80
        x(1) = 50 : y(1) = 70
        x(2) = 80 : y(2) = 70
        x(3) = 80 : y(3) = 80
        x(4) = 65 : y(4) = 80
        x(5) = 55 : y(5) = 80
        x(6) = 55 : y(6) = 130
        x(7) = 65 : y(7) = 130
        x(8) = 45 : y(8) = 120
        x(9) = 40 : y(9) = 130
        x(10) = 40 : y(10) = 110
        x(11) = 45 : y(11) = 110

    End Sub

    Private Sub drawPolygon(ByRef x() As Single, ByRef y() As Single, ByVal totPoints As Integer, ByRef g As Graphics)
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To totPoints - 1 Step 1
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x(i), y(i), x(i + 1), y(i + 1))
        Next
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x(1), y(1), x(totPoints), y(totPoints))
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnDraw_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnDraw.Click
        PictureBox1.Refresh()
        Call drawPolygon(triangX, triangY, 12, g)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rotateFigure(ByRef x() As Single, ByRef y() As Single, ByVal totPoints As Integer, ByVal angle As Single)

        Dim nx As Single
        Dim ny As Single
        Dim i As Integer
        angle = angle * Math.PI / 180
        For i = 1 To totPoints Step 1
            nx = x(i) * Math.Cos(angle) - y(i) * Math.Sin(angle)
            ny = x(i) * Math.Sin(angle) + y(i) * Math.Cos(angle)
            x(i) = nx
            y(i) = ny
        Next i
    End Sub

    Private Sub rotateFigure2(ByRef x() As Single, ByRef y() As Single, ByVal totPoints As Integer, ByVal angle As Single)

        Dim nx As Single
        Dim ny As Single
        Dim i As Integer
        angle = angle * Math.PI / 180
        For i = 1 To totPoints Step 1
            nx = x(i) * Math.Sin(angle) - y(i) * Math.Cos(angle)
            ny = x(i) * Math.Cos(angle) + y(i) * Math.Sin(angle)
            x(i) = nx
            y(i) = ny
        Next i
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnRotate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnRotate.Click
        Call rotateFigure(triangX, triangY, 14, 14)
    End Sub

    Private Sub rotateAroundPoint(ByRef x As Single, ByRef y As Single, ByVal angle As Single, ByVal xp As Single, ByVal yp As Single)


        Dim nx, ny As Single
        angle = angle * Math.PI / 180
        nx = ((x - xp) * Math.Cos(angle) - (y - yp) * Math.Sin(angle)) + xp
        ny = ((x - xp) * Math.Sin(angle) + (y - yp) * Math.Cos(angle)) + yp
        x = nx
        y = ny
    End Sub

    Private Sub rotateFigureAroundPivot(ByRef x() As Single, ByRef y() As Single, ByVal angle As Single, ByVal xp As Single, ByVal yp As Single, ByVal totpoints As Integer)

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To totpoints Step 1
            Call rotateAroundPoint(x(i), y(i), angle, xp, yp)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnRotateAroundPivot_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnRotateAroundPivot.Click
        Call rotateFigureAroundPivot(triangX, triangY, 12, triangX(0), triangY(0), 12)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Call rotateFigureAroundPivot(triangX, triangY, 12, triangX(0), triangY(0), 12)
        PictureBox1.Refresh()
        Call drawPolygon(triangX, triangY, 12, g)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnActivateTimer_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnActivateTimer.Click
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Call rotateFigure2(triangX, triangY, 112, 12)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

The values of `Math.PI` etc. are all doubles.
Either change your `triangX` and `triangY` to double or cast the result to single.

Two problems I see with your code.
First you have 12 points yet you are using 14 points there

```
Call rotateFigure(triangX, triangY, 14, 14)
```

or 112 points there

```
Call rotateFigure2(triangX, triangY, 112, 12)
```

Second arrays in vb.net start with index 0.
If you want to change all points in a loop you need to use

```
For i = 0 To totpoints - 1 Step 1
```

and `drawPolygon` should be

```
For i = 0 To totPoints - 2 Step 1
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x(i), y(i), x(i + 1), y(i + 1))
Next
g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x(0), y(0), x(totPoints - 1), y(totPoints - 1))
```